# std::string.append("\r\n\r\n") adds c62;9;c62;9; to end of string?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to append the sentinel ("\r\n\r\n") for an HTTP response to a `std::string` in C++. However, when I append the data, I get a whole bunch of extra stuff: `^[[?62;9;c^[[?62;9;c[`, followed by my programs termination. Then it writes the following to the command line: `62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c`. This only seems to happen with *.jpg/*.gif files, I have tested and verified the same method working with text and html files.

The context is that I am trying to write this string to a socket, using `string.c_str()`. I have traced the extra characters to the append operation that I do, after reading the desired file. I think this is throwing my calculated content-length off, causing the crash. So I just need to know why this extra stuff ends up in my `string.c_str()`?

**EDIT:** Here is my file reading code. (Forgot to paste it)(BUFFER_LENGTH is #defined as 1024)

```
    int fd = open(filename.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
    int bytesRead = 0;
    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    string content = "";
    while((bytesRead = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH)) !=0)
    {           
        if(bytesRead==-1)
        {
            if(errno == EINTR)
            {
                printf("\nERRONO");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nclosing fd");
                close(fd);
            }
        }  
        content+= buffer;
    }
    close(fd);
    //Printing content.c_str() here gives right value
    content += "\r\n\r\n";
    //Printing content.c_str() here gives the gibberish, and crash when I write it to the socket.
    return content;
```

Here is how I write to the socket(fdToUse is the socket):

```
write(fdToUse, response->fullResponse.c_str(), response->fullResponse.length());
close(fdToUse);
```

Comment: Post the code. My bet is that you have a bug.

Comment: Post some code please. As it is, nobody will be able to really help (just a wild guesses)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Forgot to paste it. Added.

Comment: I wish I could accept both K-ballo and Remy's comments. They both work well. Remy has the answer because his made more sense for binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not managing the file data very well.  You really should not be storing binary data into a std::string to begin with.  It would be better to calculate the file size ahead of time, send the `Content-Length` header, then read the file contents into a binary buffer and send the buffer as you are reading the file.

If you must use a std::string, then you should at least use something more like this instead:

```
std::string content;

int fd = open(filename.c_str(), O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
if (fd != -1)
{
    long filesize = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        content.resize(filesize);

        int total = 0, bytesRead;
        while (total < filesize)
        {
            bytesRead = read(fd, &content[total], filesize-total);
            if (bytesRead == -1)
            {
                printf("\nERRNO");
                content.resize(0);
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                printf("\nUnexpected EOF");
                content.resize(0);
                break;
            }

            total += bytesRead;
        }
    }

    close(fd);
}

content += "\r\n\r\n";
return content;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. As I said before in an earlier comment, C++ is probably my worst language. I have it in an std::string . . . well, because thats all I knew how to do. If I am correct; I could use this (or something like it) to send text/html as well?

Answer (score 6):

`^[[?62;9;c` is a VT100 control sequence reporting the terminal's status (DA1). Chances are that the binary data in the GIF/JPG you're outputting to the terminal contains a sequence which is causing your local terminal to respond in an unexpected fashion.

The specific sequence you're seeing the results of is documented at http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html (search for "primary DA"), but the details aren't directly relevant here. What matters is simply that your terminal is generating some output when it sees a certain sequence on input.

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for, but really cool info nonetheless! Thanks!

Comment: +1 pretty useful info for me, outside the scope of this question

Answer (score 6):

```
content+= buffer;
```

should be:

```
content.insert( content.size(), buffer, bytesRead );
```

Comment: This looks like what I need after reading the documentation. Final question: using this, I get an error saying "invalid conversion from char* to long unsigned int", on argument 2. However, there is a constructor that says it takes a char* there? Kinda lost, since C++ is definitely not my language.